# Convert sqlite3 to mysql under python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I am converting a python script to use mysql instead of sqlite3 and i am having a lot of issues with mysql syntax errors which have really stumped me to this point. I don't have much experience with databases. It seems the lines will work for a short time then they throw errors.

This is the line that gives me the first error. I think once i get the syntax right i can change all of the others as well.

```
        elif 'Sensors' in line:
        Sensors,pH1,pH2,Temp,RH,TDS1,TDS2,CO2,Light,Water,MagX,MagY,MagZ,TankTotal,Tank1,Tank2,Tank3,Tank4,WaterTempP1,WaterTempP2,WaterTempP3,WaterTempP4=line.split(",")
        Sensors = Sensors.replace("Read fail", "")
        WaterTempP4 = WaterTempP4.rstrip()
        elapsedTime = now-startTime
        elapsedSeconds = (elapsedTime.microseconds+(elapsedTime.days*24*3600+elapsedTime.seconds)*10**6)/10**6
        print("\033[10;0H\r")
        print("\033[10;0H(" + now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") + ") Sensors: %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s"%(pH1,pH2,Temp,RH,TDS1,TDS2,CO2,Light,Water,MagX,MagY,MagZ,TankTotal,Tank1,Tank2,Tank3,Tank4,WaterTempP1,WaterTempP2,WaterTempP3,WaterTempP4))
        now = datetime.now()
        delta = float(now.strftime('%s')) - float(LastDataPoint_Time.strftime('%s'))
        if (delta < 0):
            TimeString = LastDataPoint_Time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            update_sql("DELETE FROM Sensors_Log WHERE Time='" + TimeString + "'")
            LastDataPoint_Time = datetime.now()
            addMessageLog("Negative Delta - Deleting Last Record (Wrong Time?)")
            printMessageLog()
        if (delta >= TakeDataPoint_Every) or (Datapoint_count == 0 and first_timesync == True):
            addMessageLog("Added a data point to the sensor values log.")
            printMessageLog()
            update_sql("INSERT INTO Sensors_Log (Time,pH1,pH2,Temp,RH,TDS1,TDS2,CO2,Light,Water,MagX,MagY,MagZ,TankTotal,Tank1,Tank2,Tank3,Tank4,WaterTempP1,WaterTempP2,WaterTempP3,WaterTempP4) VALUES ('" + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "'," + pH1 + "," + pH2+ "," + Temp + "," + RH + "," + TDS1 + "," + TDS2 + "," + CO2 + "," + Light  + "," + Water + "," + MagX + "," + MagY + "," + MagZ + "," + TankTotal + "," + Tank1 + "," + Tank2 + "," + Tank3 + "," + Tank4 + "," + WaterTempP1 + "," + WaterTempP2 + "," + WaterTempP3 + "," + WaterTempP4 + ")")
            LastDataPoint_Time = datetime.now()
            timesync = 0 #do a timesync
            Datapoint_count = Datapoint_count + 1
        #SENSOR VALUES
        update_sql("UPDATE `Sensors` SET pH1 = " + pH1 + ", pH2 = " + pH2 + ", Temp = " + Temp + ", RH = " + RH + ", TDS1 = " + TDS1 + ", TDS2 = " + TDS2 + ", CO2 = " + CO2 + ", Light = " + Light + ", Water = " + Water + ", MagX = " + MagX + ", MagY = " + MagY + ", MagZ = " + MagZ + ", TankTotal = " + TankTotal + ", Tank1 = " + Tank1 + ", Tank2 = " + Tank2 + ", Tank3 = " + Tank3 + ", Tank4 = " + Tank4 + ", WaterTempP1 = " + WaterTempP1 + ", WaterTempP2 = " + WaterTempP2 + ", WaterTempP3 = " + WaterTempP3 + ", WaterTempP4 = " + WaterTempP4 + "")

        db.commit()
```

Its the update_sql("UPDATE string at the bottom that throws a 1064 error any help to set me on the right track with the format would be greatly appreciated. The code above runs when a serial string comes in with 'Sensors' in the serial string. It is followed by sensor readings separated by commas. The code seems to work ok when inserting but not updating.

thanks in advance

here is the full error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yieldbuddy.py", line 1211, in <module>
    serialerr=checkSerial()
  File "yieldbuddy.py", line 481, in checkSerial
    update_sql("UPDATE `Sensors` SET pH1 = " + pH1 + ", pH2 = " + pH2 + ", Temp = " + Temp + ", RH = " + RH + ", TDS1 = " + TDS1 + ", TDS2 = " + TDS2 + ", CO2 = " + CO2 + ", Light = " + Light + ", Water = " + Water + ", MagX = " + MagX + ", MagY = " + MagY + ", MagZ = " + MagZ + ", TankTotal = " + TankTotal + ", Tank1 = " + Tank1 + ", Tank2 = " + Tank2 + ", Tank3 = " + Tank3 + ", Tank4 = " + Tank4 + ", WaterTempP1 = " + WaterTempP1 + ", WaterTempP2 = " + WaterTempP2 + ", WaterTempP3 = " + WaterTempP3 + ", WaterTempP4 = " + WaterTempP4 + "")
  File "yieldbuddy.py", line 33, in update_sql
    cursor.execute(query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")
```

I have been using the 3rd example below to setup the sql update statements this seems to be working until i reached the following code

```
            elif 'SetPoint_pH2' in line:
            if oldSetPoint_pH2 != line:
                oldSetPoint_pH2 = line
                #print("%s"%(line))  For Debugging
                SetPoint_pH2,pH2Value_Low,pH2Value_High,pH2_Status=line.split(",")
                SetPoint_pH2 = SetPoint_pH2.replace("Read fail", "")
                pH2_Status = pH2_Status.rstrip()
                print("\033[16;0H                                                                                                                       ")
                print("\033[16;0H(" + now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") + ") SetPoint_pH2: %s,%s,%s"%(pH2Value_Low,pH2Value_High,pH2_Status))
                #SetPoint_pH
#               update_sql("UPDATE `pH2` SET Low='" + pH2Value_Low + "',High='" + pH2Value_High + "',Status='" + pH2_Status + "'")
                update_sql("UPDATE `pH2` SET Low = {}, High = {}, Status = {}".format(pH2Value_Low,pH2Value_High,pH2_Status))
```

For some reason it doesn't recogninze the status field as being status column in database instead its throwing this error.

```
(2016/08/07 12:10:42) SetPoint_pH2: -1.00,6.20,OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yieldbuddy.py", line 1310, in <module>
    serialerr=checkSerial()
  File "yieldbuddy.py", line 607, in checkSerial
    update_sql("UPDATE `pH2` SET Low = {}, High = {}, Status = {}".format(pH2Value_Low,pH2Value_High,pH2_Status))
  File "yieldbuddy.py", line 33, in update_sql
    cursor.execute(query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'OK' in 'field list'")
```

I can't seem to see the difference between this line and the others i have already done, it tries to use the column "ok" which is actually the value i want to put into the actual column "Status".

Comment: Wouldn't it have made more sense to have posted just the offending query and the full error message?

Comment: Put a „print” before update_sql, and show output, the one that work and the one that don't. And yes @e4c5 is right, error message is usefull

Comment: Also, a good lesson for using some DBMS-agnostic framework next time, like SQLAlchemy ;)!

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, your UPDATE SQL statement is correct according to the `SET` clause and placement of equal signs and commas. Most likely what's happening is one or more of your 21 variables is returning a zero length string (`''`) which MySQL cannot set to a numeric column. Consider converting such zero length strings conditionally to `None` which translates in MySQL as `NULL`.

As example, below shows an empty value for `v5`

```
line = "this,is,a,test,"
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = line.split(",")
print(v5=='')
# TRUE
```

To resolve, conditionally generate `None` for such zero-length strings:

```
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = [None if i == '' else i for i in [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]]
print(v5==None)    # ALTERNATIVELY: print(v5 is None)
# TRUE
```

---

Therefore, consider the following adjustment at the top when variables are initialized:

```
...
Sensors,pH1,pH2,Temp,RH,TDS1,TDS2,CO2,Light,Water,MagX,MagY,MagZ,TankTotal,\
Tank1,Tank2,Tank3,Tank4,WaterTempP1,WaterTempP2,WaterTempP3,WaterTempP4 = line.split(",")

Sensors,pH1,pH2,Temp,RH,TDS1,TDS2,CO2,Light,Water,MagX,MagY,MagZ,TankTotal,\
Tank1,Tank2,Tank3,Tank4,WaterTempP1,WaterTempP2,WaterTempP3,WaterTempP4 = \
   [None if i == '' else i for i in [Sensors,pH1,pH2,Temp,RH,TDS1,TDS2,CO2,Light,Water,\
                                     MagX,MagY,MagZ,TankTotal,Tank1,Tank2,Tank3,Tank4,\
                                     WaterTempP1,WaterTempP2,WaterTempP3,WaterTempP4]]
```

Then, wrap each variable in `str()` since the `NoneType` object requires explicit conversion of string not implicit with concatenation. Update below will set MySQL columns to `NULL` at every instance of Python's `None`:

```
update_sql("UPDATE `Sensors` SET pH1 = " + str(pH1) + ", " + \
            "pH2 = " + str(pH2) + ", Temp = " + str(Temp) + ", RH = " + str(RH) + ", " + \
            "TDS1 = " + str(TDS1) + ", TDS2 = " + str(TDS2) + ", CO2 = " + str(CO2) + ", " + \
            "Light = " + str(Light) + ", Water = " + str(Water) + ", MagX = " + str(MagX) + ", " + \
            "MagY = " + str(MagY) + ", MagZ = " + str(MagZ) + ", TankTotal = " + str(TankTotal) + ", " + \
            "Tank1 = " + str(Tank1) + ", Tank2 = " + str(Tank2) + ", Tank3 = " + str(Tank3) + ", " + \
            "Tank4 = " + str(Tank4) + ", WaterTempP1 = " + str(WaterTempP1) + ", " + \
            "WaterTempP2 = " + str(WaterTempP2) + ", WaterTempP3 = " + str(WaterTempP3) + ", " + \
            "WaterTempP4 = " + str(WaterTempP4) + "")
```

Alternatively, consider string formatting which also accommodates `None`:

```
update_sql("UPDATE `Sensors` SET pH1 = {}, \
            pH2 = {}, Temp = {}, RH = {}, \
            TDS1 = {}, TDS2 = {}, CO2 = {},  \
            Light = {}, Water = {}, MagX = {},  \
            MagY = {}, MagZ = {}, TankTotal = {},  \
            Tank1 = {}, Tank2 = {}, Tank3 = {}, \
            Tank4 = {}, WaterTempP1 = {}, \
            WaterTempP2 = {}, WaterTempP3 = {}, \
            WaterTempP4 = {} ".format(pH1,pH2,Temp,RH,TDS1,TDS2,CO2,Light,Water,\
                                      MagX,MagY,MagZ,TankTotal,Tank1,Tank2,Tank3,Tank4,\
                                      WaterTempP1,WaterTempP2,WaterTempP3,WaterTempP4))
```

Even better, run the update as a parameterized query within [cursor.execute()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) method and do so if source data comes from external sources to avoid sql injection:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE `Sensors` SET pH1 = %s, \
             pH2 = %s, Temp = %s, RH = %s, \
             TDS1 = %s, TDS2 = %s, CO2 = %s, \
             Light = %s, Water = %s, MagX = %s, \
             MagY = %s, MagZ = %s, TankTotal = %s, \
             Tank1 = %s, Tank2 = %s, Tank3 = %s,  \
             Tank4 = %s, WaterTempP1 = %s, \
             WaterTempP2 = %s, WaterTempP3 = %s, \
             WaterTempP4 = %s ", \
             (pH1,pH2,Temp,RH,TDS1,TDS2,CO2,Light,Water,MagX,MagY,MagZ,\
              TankTotal,Tank1,Tank2,Tank3,Tank4,\
              WaterTempP1,WaterTempP2,WaterTempP3,WaterTempP4)
db.commit()
```

Comment: the examples above have been very helpful in getting me started with converting some of the sqlite3 lines i have been stumped by one line which does not want to work right. I updated the original message to show the line that refuses to work, Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Forgive me, but it seems you are changing your initial issue and might need to ask a different question. For this answer, did the first failed update query issue derive from an empty value in one of the 21 variables?

Comment: As for your edit, simply wrap the `Status` value in single quotes since it appears to be a string column: `"UPDATE pH2 SET Low = {}, High = {}, Status = '{}'".format(pH2Value_Low, pH2Value_High, pH2_Status)`

Comment: i changed the update_sql commands to look like the 2nd to last example above using the .format part and this corrected the issue with the 21 variables in the first line in my message, I have been doing the exact same thing as that with all the other lines in the code simalar to the first one. when i get to field like the one i just added it seems to be having issues with the "ok" in the status field for the setpoints instead of updating the database with the value OK its using OK as the column to update instead. In all other places i changed it works

Comment: Thank you so much by adding the ' ' around the brackets where status = has corrected the issue. Its pretty apparent i have a lot to study and learn about formatting things for mysql. The lines where all original working with a sqlite3 database which was too slow for my purpose

Comment: Great to hear it's working. Do accept this answer it if helped and to confirm resolution. Indeed, SQLite is a file level RDMS while MySQL is a server-level RDMS. However, unless you are handling millions of records, SQLite is still powerful with [terabyte scalability](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html), indexing, and window fcts for optimization.